# How to make a function run along with my views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this function, I want it to be working with my view, how could I do it ?

```
def PlaySound(self):
    while(True):
        if GPIO.input(Snare) == False:
        os.system("path/to/the/sound")
    return ("Is activated")
```

---

```
def view(request):
    return render(request, "page.html")
```

Comment: Why can't you just call it?

Comment: How do I do it ?

Comment: Same as any other function: `PlaySound()`.

Comment: So, Do I call the function in the fbv, right ?

Comment: I'm getting an error, Take exacly 1 argument (0 given), but my function doesn't need parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PlaySound` is not a method of a class, then you don't need `self`. use `def PlaySound():`.

```
def PlaySound():
    ...
```

You can then call the method in the view, before you return the response.

```
def view(request):
    PlaySound()
    return render(request, "page.html")
```

Comment: PlaySound Takes exacly 1 argument (0 given), but my function doesn't need parameters

Comment: If you get that error, then you haven't changed `def PlaySound(self):` to `def PlaySound():` as I suggested.

Comment: When I type the url the function runs but the view doesn't render, it is loading forever.., I would like to have a code running after the view is rendered.

Comment: PlaySound runs, but render doesn't return the page.html

Comment: That's because your `PlaySound` method never exits the `while(True):` loop, so the view will never finish.

Comment: Is there any way to call the function just when the view is rendered ?

Comment: Returning the response is the last thing the view does, you can't do anything afterwards. If you want the `PlaySound` function to continue to run after the view has returned, you'd have to spawn a process.

Comment: Could you provide some resources so I can study and try to do it ?, This question is already solved even though I didn't manage to do what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143900/discussion-between-goun2-and-alasdair).